# Android appcompat custom drawer with something like hook?

Tags: android, customization, navigation-drawer

I had done normal drawer by following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) tuts.but i need to implement custom drawer using android latest technique like below image for showing latest user notification count if any.
[image]

Actually i need the following hook shapes.

**Drawer open state**

[image]

**Drawer closed state**

[image]

I tried with 9 patch image but when closing the drawer the color of the hook is updating to red.I'm totally confused.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what your saying is that you have it working but on close its red?

Answer (score 0):

Create RelativieLayout which contain your listview and add imagebutton .and change image as you specify you are using 9patch image . on drawer open and close as implement drawer listener as shown below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_slider"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_slider_indicator"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And implement Listener which change your image in imagebutton

## note taking from developer.google.com

```
  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                //update your image view of imagebutton
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //update your image on imagebutton   
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: isn't working.the hook is hiding with drawer layout when hiding.

Comment: and also `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated.